# Is there a CMakeLists configuration for referencing packages to each other?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS: `melodic`
Linux: `18.04`

When i `catkin_make` when `module_one` find package `module_two` and `module_two` find package `module_one`, there is error like below

> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'module_one'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(module_one)
> -- Could NOT find module_two (missing: module_two_DIR)
> -- Could not find the required component 'module_two'. The following
> CMake error indicates that you either
> need to install the package with the
> same name or change your environment
> so that it can be found. CMake Error
> at
> /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "module_two" with   any of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> module_twoConfig.cmake
> module_two-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "module_two" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
> set   "module_two_DIR" to a directory
> containing one of the above files.  If
> "module_two" provides a separate
> development package or SDK, be sure it
> has   been installed. Call Stack (most
> recent call first):
> module_one/CMakeLists.txt:10
> (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
> "/home/ri/workspace/catkin_playground/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also
> "/home/ri/workspace/catkin_playground/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

the workspace folder tree is below

> ├── build
> │   ├── atomic_configure
> │   ├── catkin
> │   │   └── catkin_generated
> │   │       └── version
> │   ├── catkin_generated
> │   │   ├── installspace
> │   │   └── stamps
> │   │       └── Project
> │   ├── CMakeFiles
> │   │   ├── 3.11.0
> │   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
> │   │   │   │   └── tmp
> │   │   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
> │   │   │       └── tmp
> │   │   └── CMakeTmp
> │   ├── gtest
> │   │   ├── CMakeFiles
> │   │   └── googlemock
> │   │       ├── CMakeFiles
> │   │       └── gtest
> │   │           └── CMakeFiles
> │   ├── module_one
> │   │   └── CMakeFiles
> │   └── test_results
> ├── devel
> │   └── lib
> └── src
> ├── module_one
> └── module_two

module_one and module_two are pacakage individually.

module_one's CMakeLists.txt has

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED module_two)
```

module_two's CMakeLists.txt has

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED module_one)
```

like the above project,
Is there a CMakeLists configuration for referencing packages to each other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381205/is-there-a-cmakelists-configuration-for-referencing-packages-to-each-other?/) by [Kyuhwan Yeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/52761/kyuhwan-yeon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regardless of the error you mention, two CMake packages cannot depend on each other *directly*. Circular dependencies are unsupported.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kyuhwan Yeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/52761/kyuhwan-yeon/) on 2021-06-29**:
Thank you. that's correct. the real problem was i tried the circular dependency!. I will reconstruct my packages thank you!